# How to filter pandas dataframe columns by partial label

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to filter pandas dataframe columns (with type `pandas.core.index.Index`) by a partial label.

I am searching for a builtin method that achieve the same result as:

```
partial_label = 'partial_lab'
columns = df.columns
columns = [c for c in columns if c.startswith(partial_label)]
df = df[columns]
```

Is there anything builtin to obtain this?

Thanks

Comment: see [.filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas.DataFrame.filter); it has support for regex

Comment: It works, post it as answer please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

possible solutions:

```
df.filter(regex='partial_lab.*')
```

or

```
idx = df.columns.to_series().str.startswith('partial_lab')
df.loc[:,idx]
```

Comment: IMO is more elegant the first solution. Thanks :)